# rails 4 autoloading String class extensions (located in /lib)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A very simple questions: I create a file named `string.rb` in the `/lib` directory. As far as I know, rails will expect this file to define the `String` class, so I included the following code in this file:

```
class String
  def say
    puts "syaing #{self}"
  end
end
```

I'd expect the console to print "say ben" after typing `"ben".say`, but in fact, I got an unknown_method error (when I `load 'lib/string.rb'` it's fine). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to application.rb file

```
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

But I'd prefer to patch base class locating it in config/initializers directory.

Comment: 1. I have `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` in my ` application.rb`, how is it different?
2. Why placing it in the initializers folder is better the the "lib" approach?

Comment: Actually it's the same.
Just move to config/initializers. It is good practice to keep monkey patches there.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to config/initializers